# Tried to dual-boot ubuntu and win10, got RST error, switched to AHCI and now windows won't boot

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, boot, intel-rst

I decided to dual boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04.1 (UEFI, Dell Inspiron 3583), and got myself a USB flash drive to do so. Shortly into the install, I got an error about RST needing to be changed to AHCI, coupled with a link (https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/ubuntu-installation-on-computers-with-intel-r-rst-enabled/15347), so I followed the instructions. rather than reaching the displayed BSOD in the case which something went wrong, I got a different screen, and clicking on recovery options restarts back to the same screen. I can no longer follow the tutorial, and can't get myself a windows recovery disc/USB at the moment because the only one I have already has Ubuntu and is too small for windows to fit on anyways. How would I go about fixing this problem?

EDIT: it seems that i was able to fix it simply by switching back to RST (although, it didn't work the first time i tried it, but for some reason did on attempt 2). unfortunately, that leaves me right back where i started, as i'm still not in AHCI mode, however windows now boots correctly, and my files are intact.

EDIT 2: I've managed to do it through this method: https://www.tenforums.com/drivers-hardware/15006-attn-ssd-owners-enabling-ahci-mode-after-windows-10-installation.html

Comment: Go back to AHCI and reinstall everything from scratch. Format the disk as GPT.

Comment: won't that erase all the data on the drive?

Comment: Yes, when changing from SATA/AHCI this is the simplest way. Unless the installations were previously done in AHCI.

Comment: okay then, is there any way to recover the data? while not much, i do have some things i'd like to save.

Comment: You may backup and restore all except for the OS.